# Is there any compatibility issue with Amazon Aurora?

Tags: 7, database

I'm exploring the possibility of using Aurora as a database backend for a large-ish Drupal 7 site because of the potential performance gains. Before I do that, though, I'd like to know if there are any outstanding issues with this kind of setup.

So far, the only resource I've found are [this fixed Drupal.org issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2777425) and [a number of rather old questions on this site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aurora?sort=votes&pageSize=15). I'm still a bit concerned because the Aurora FAQ [states](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/):

> **Q: What does "MySQL-compatible" mean?**
>
> It means that ***most*** of the code, applications, drivers and tools you already use today with your MySQL databases can be used with Aurora with little or no change. The Amazon Aurora database engine is designed to be wire-compatible with MySQL 5.6 using the InnoDB storage engine. Certain MySQL features like the MyISAM storage engine are not available with Amazon Aurora.

(Emphasis mine)

It's the "most" that has me worried, specifically. Are there any pitfalls when using Drupal 7 with Aurora?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! How much a database engine is compatible with MySQL is not a Drupal-specific question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I'm asking specifically whether any incompatibility between Aurora and MySQL affects Drupal, not how compatible it is with MySQL. If I were asking that, I'd post to the DBA StackExchange.

Comment: Since Drupal uses the PDO classes PHP has, your question gets the same answer it would be given for a plain PHP application using the same classes. If the FAQ doesn't list which features aren't compatible with MySQL, I am not sure in which way we could know that.

Comment: If you are worried about some modules not working fine with Aurora, you could test those modules with a site using that database engine. A generic answer about that is not possible.

Comment: `I am not sure in which way we could know that.` Honestly, I was hoping people could speak from experienced _because_ of the lack of details on the page -- but you make a good point. I'll post to DBA.SE if this question doesn't get answers in the next few hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aurora isn't widely used in the community, but all the materials I've seen say it works ([like this post](https://www.karelbemelmans.com/2016/06/running-drupal-7-on-aws---part-1/)).

To test a setup using AWS you could use the [test drives setup by Acquia](https://aws.amazon.com/testdrive/drupal/). I'm not sure if they are running Aurora on those or not, but it is probably worth a look.

As for testing custom modules there is a degree to which you cannot know until you either check a module and test it out, but *most* Drupal 7 contrib modules make use of Drupal's internal query APIs and therefore *should* not present issues on Aurora.

Answer (score 9):

We are running a couple of projects on Amazon Aurora  with no issues so far. Our largest project is a D7 project with many contributed modules, and a large amount of data being moved.

We've never noticed any DB related issues aside from normal MySQLisms. It's really transparent to Drupal. We use normal Mysql connection strings and zero core changes.

Aurora is more expensive. A lot more expensive. It only starts at the db.r3.large tier, and works out to a monthly (non upfront rate of 0.190 per hour). So the price difference must be considered.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/89326)

Comment: I contest that. He is asking if Amazon Aurora has any issues with Drupal I stated that I use Amazon Aurora on a number of projects with no issues. How is this not an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have not experienced any compatibility issues on 2 mid-size projects with over 100k nodes and over 20k users on D7.

One of the sites I'm looking at has about 20 custom modules and 80 contrib ones.